# Updating a score (+1) in mysql table everytime an image is clicked (<a>). Using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, onclick

I'm working on a website just now, and basically it has 2 images next to each other.

What I want to happen is when you click one, and not the other, it will update the score in the database +1 for the photo you clicked.

Just now both pictures seem to be getting their score in their respective tables updated by 1, but both on page load which is annoying.

I am only wanting the score for the one the user clicks to update by 1 in the db.

Is it because it is located within the  tag?

Here is the code, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 

//Connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password")
    or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database")
    or die("Could not connect to database, ".mysql_error());

//Variables
$thisPage = "index.php";

$count_query_cat1= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cat1`");
$count_query_cat2= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cat2`");

$count_num_cat1 = mysql_fetch_array($count_query_cat1);
$count_num_cat2 = mysql_fetch_array($count_query_cat2);


if (isset($_GET['cat1']))
{
    $id_cat1 = (int) $_GET['cat1'];
}

if (isset($_GET['cat2']))
{
    $id_cat2 = (int) $_GET['cat2'];
}

if ($id_cat1 == 0)
{
    $url = $thisPage."?cat1=".$count_num_cat1[0]."&cat2=".$count_num_cat2[0];
    header("Location: $url");
}


$query_cat1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = $id_cat1");
$result_cat1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_cat1);

$query_cat2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = $id_cat2");
$result_cat2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_cat2);

$image_cat1 = "<img src=\"{$result_cat1['path']}\" class=\"content_image\" alt=\"{$result_cat1['description']}\" title=\"{$result_cat1['description']}\" /><br />";
$image_cat1 = "<img src=\"{$result_cat2['path']}\" class=\"content_image\" alt=\"{$result_cat2['description']}\" title=\"{$result_cat2['description']}\" /><br />";


$description_cat1 = $result_cat1['description'];
$description_cat2 = $result_cat2['description'];


//Random button
$random_cat1 = rand(1,$count_num_cat1[0]);
if ($random_cat1 == $count_num_cat1[0]){
    $random_cat1 = rand(1,$count_num_cat1[0]);
}

$random_cat2 = rand(1,$count_num_cat2[0]);
if ($random_cat2 == $count_num_cat2[0]){
    $random_cat2 = rand(1,$count_num_cat2[0]);
}

$random_btn = "{$thisPage}?cat1={$random_cat1}&cat2={$random_cat2}";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $pageTitle; ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="index.php"><div id="home_icon" alth="Home Icon" title="Home"></div></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $random_btn; ?>"><div id="random_icon" alth="Random Icon" title="Random"></div></a>
        <div id="image_title">
            <p>TITLE</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

    <!-- Content [Image] cat1 -->

        <a href="<?php mysql_query("UPDATE `table1` SET `score` = `score` + 1 WHERE `id` = $id_cat1"); echo $random_btn; ?>"><?php echo $image_cat1; ?></a><br/>

    <!-- Content [Image] cat2 -->

    <a href="<?php mysql_query("UPDATE `table2` SET `score` = `score` + 1 WHERE `id` = $id_cat2"); echo $random_btn; ?>"><?php echo $image_cat2; ?></a><br/>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use AJAX or just a normal form?

Comment: `<a href="<?php mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET score = score + 1 WHERE id = $id_cat1"); echo $random_btn; ?>"><?php echo $image_cat1; ?></a>` <-- that's not how things work, Robbie.

Comment: well how do they work? Can you explain why it doesn't work please?

Comment: either you make it a form or you link it like this `<a href="index.php?action=vote&cat=1">`. Then just check the GET Superglobals and update your table.

Comment: How can i do it through a form?

I would prefer not to do it through the URL.

Comment: @RobbieSeath, I would recommend looking up some basic php forms tutorials because you really don't seem to know the difference between server-side and client-side. Also, do not use any `mysql_*` functions as they are discouraged and will be deprecated soon. Instead use PDO or mysqli for your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code gets executed on page load, unless stated otherwise (by some IF statement or such).
So, if you put any kind of PHP code inside your HTML tag, like here:

```
<a href="<?php mysql_query("UPDATE `table2` SET `score` = `score` + 1 WHERE `id` = $id_cat2"); echo $random_btn; ?>"><?php echo $image_cat2; ?></a><br/>
```

code you wrote inside of href attribute gets executed, no matter whether the link is clicked or not.

Solution is as following:
In href attribute, write **"?update_photo=1"**, and in the ohter anchor write **href="?update_photo=2"**.

Inside the PHP tags write the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['update_photo'])){
    $id = (int)$_GET['update_photo'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `table2` SET `score` = `score` + 1 WHERE `id` = {$id}");
}
```

Comment: Actually, php code gets executed before page load. The (abbreviated) lifecycle of a web request is such; User requests something (typically a web page, by clicking a link), the browser makes an HTTP request to the server, the server receives the request, and decides what to do with it. This is where php actually does stuff like connecting to the database, making other requests, etc. Whatever php `echo`s out will be your response.

Comment: @kosturko - Thank you very much! I had to edit your solution a little bit to work for my code (had to make 2 if statements, 1 per table), but you sent me on the right tracks :)